# How to document an object property?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I document an object property with the object properties expected?
For instance, if the object was this:

```
var Object = {
    /**
     * 
     */
    point: null
}
```

and the point had this structure:

```
{
    x,
    y
}
```

Is there anyway to say that the point should have the x and y property?
Well, of course I can do it in the description, but I was looking for a better way to do it, like in the params that we can do like this:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} point
 * @param {Number} point.x
 * @param {Number} point.y
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always make a `Point` class.

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Then

```
var Object = {
    /**
     * new Point(x, y)
     * @param {Point} point a point class
     */
    point: null
}
```

Other wise I would do

```
/*
 * @param {Object} point {x, y}
 */
```

Comment: Sometimes I don't want to have a class definition, and others the object needs comments in their properties thus invalidating the second option.
It would be nice to have the @typedef like google closure have, to fake a class without an entry in the classes list, but providing a link to it.
But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah. I typically go with my 2nd option and use the object structure as the comment.